# Python script is only extracting the last index rather than all - Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The output for the code below is only giving me the stock price and name for the second url rather than both. 
I tried looking through the comments to see if anybody else encountered this problem but nobody else asked this question. Code is in Python 2

quote_page = ['http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/SPX:IND', 'http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/CCMP:IND']

```
data = []

for pg in quote_page:
    page = urllib2.urlopen(pg)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

name_box = soup.find('h1', attrs = {'class':'name'})
name = name_box.text.strip() 

price_box = soup.find('div', attrs = {'class':'price'})
price = price_box.text

data.append((name, price))

with open('output/stock.csv','a') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for name, price in data:
        writer.writerow([name, price, datetime.now()])
```

Comment: the scrapped `page` is defined in the loop, so you have to indent all the following code (not the `with` statement)

Answer (score 0):

It was because of the faulty indentation. Give this a try. It will fix the issue. I've also make it a little shorter by shaking off redundant part. Change the portion necessary to be usable in python 2.

```
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

quote_page = ['http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/SPX:IND', 'http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/CCMP:IND']

for pg in quote_page:
    page = urlopen(pg).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')
    name = soup.find(class_='name').text.strip()
    price = soup.find(class_='price').text
    print(name,price)
    with open('stock.csv','a') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerow([name, price])
```

Answer (score 0):

## Boolmberg

```
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime

quote_page = ['http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/SPX:IND', 'http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/CCMP:IND']

data = []

for pg in quote_page:
    page = urlopen(pg)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

    name_box = soup.find('h1', attrs={'class': 'name'})
    name = name_box.text.strip()

    price_box = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'price'})
    price = price_box.text

    data.append((name, price))

    with open('stock2.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        for name, price in data:
            writer.writerow([name, price, datetime.now()])
```